# Unable to use Windows Phone 10 Emulator

Tags: windows-phone, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise installed on my Window 10 development machine. I can create a new Universal Windows Platform app and run it both in the simulator as well as on the local machine.

However, when I select any of the 5 pre-installed Mobile Emulators and start debugging, I see the emulator app (XDE.exe) being launched, but then I immediately get an error dialog with the following message:

> The emulator is unable to set some properties on the virtual machine: Couldn't change Display controller settings of the virtual machine: .... The configuration version of the Mobile Emulator 10.0.10240.0 WVGA 4 inch ... virtual machine does not support setting resolution type, horizontal resolution or vertical resolution.

When I open the Hyper-V manager, I can see 3 virtual machines installed. I can even start them and they will eventually show the Windows Phone 10 home screen in the expected resolution and orientation.

This happens when running Visual Studio 2015 either as a regular user or as an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your computer has an internet connection, and

If the Tools for Universal Windows Apps Development are still installed:

- Go to Programs and Features, select Visual Studio 2015, click Change.
- In Visual Studio setup, click Modify.
- Deselect the feature Tools for Universal Windows App Development.
- Select Tools for Universal Windows App Development again, and click
  Update.

If you have already uninstalled the Tools for Universal Windows Apps Development: Reinstall Tools for Universal Windows App Development.
Or, take the following steps to reinstall the JavaScript project system and language service:

- Download the installer for your edition of Visual Studio, such as, vs_community.exe.
- Open a command window, and run the following command:
- vs_community.exe /modify /installselectableitems JavaScript_Hidden
  /passive
- Change directories to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  14.0\Common7\IDE
- Run the following commands:

  ```
   devenv /updateconfiguration

   devenv /clearcache
  ```

Comment: While I was on Modify window, under Tools in Universal Windows App I noticed that Emulator for Windows 10 Mobile is not selected, this is weird because I was using them couple weeks ago. I not sure how they got uninstalled :) Thank you, maybe your steps will help someone else.